# Exponent and group quotient

Tags: group-theory

We know tha if $1\not=H\trianglelefteq G$ which consists of all the elements
of $G$ which have finite order, then in $G/H$, no elements(except element
neutral) has finite order.

My question is: If $1\not=H\trianglelefteq G$ ($H\not=G$) has exponent
finite, then what can say on $G/H$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I have misinterpreted your question, nothing can be said about $G/H$. Take for example $G= H \times K$, with $H$ finite (and hence of finite exponent) and $K$ arbitrary and non-trivial. $G/H$ is isomorphic to $K$ and this group can have any property you want.

Comment: Usually, when we killed $H$ in $G/H$ , we have some property in $G/H.$

Example: If $H$ contains all the commutators of $G,$ then $G/H$ is abelian.

I thought that in the case in that $H$ has finite exponet, $G/H$  would have
some known property.

Comment: @Lima: I think you might be onto something if $H$ was a *maximal* subgroup of a given exponent (as well as normal). Or, maybe rather, if it contained *all* elements of rank smaller than some number.